# How to redirect page from default route to custom one in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to know whether there is a way to redirect page from "~/ControllerName/Index" to custom route like "~/example-custom" without using 301 redirect in URL rewrite module.

I have used routing attribute:

```
[Route("example-custom")]
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But with this routing attribute "~/ControllerName/Index" is no more. When users go to "~/ControllerName/Index", page does not exist on that route. I would like redirect users to "~/example-custom" when they want to access page.

So, what I would like in shorter terms is to browser display link "something.com/example-custom" and not "something.com/ControllerName/Index". But also accessing "something.com/ControllerName/Index" would redirect automatically to "something.com/example-custom".

Comment: What is the .net version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Add custom route into `RouteConfig.cs` File

```
public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "example-custom",
                    url: "{example-custom}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "YourControllerName", action = "YourActionName", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
       
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried that first but issue persists.
So, what I would like in shorter terms is to browser display link "https://www.something.com/example-custom" and not "https://www.something.com/ControllerName/Index". But also accessing "https://www.something.com/ControllerName/Index" would redirect automatically to "https://www.something.com/example-custom".